# Powershell search excel document for exact match

Tags: excel, powershell

I am using PowerShell to search a document for a key word (TTF) and then import some data.  I am searching a few thousand excel documents and about half way through it started picking up unwanted data.

The code I have is as follows

```
$condition1 = "TTF"
$fs1 = $ws.cells.find($condition1)
```

It started getting unwanted data as the excel documents started using "TTF All Day" in another cell which was at the start of the document.

How do I get powershell to only look for "TTF" exactly and not "TTF" followed by more characters.

Thanks

Comment: for the time being I have added in $range = $ws.Range("A25:Q104") to remove the find on any rows above 25 where the offending string is.

Answer (score 2):

```html
# This script illustrates how to use the Range.Find method 
# with parameters to find exact match
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Learn More:
#    Range.Find Method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find
#    XlFindLookIn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfindlookin
#    XlLookAt: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xllookat

# Open Excel
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible=$false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts=$false

# Open Spreadsheet you want to test
$xlSource = "C:\Temp\YourSpreadsheetNameGoesHere.xlsx"
$xlBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($xlSource)
$xlSheet = $xlBook.worksheets.item("SheetNameGoesHere")
   
# What you want to seach                 
$searchString = "John Smith"
    
# Column or Range you want to seach
$searchRange = $xlSheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn
    
# Search
$search = $searchRange.find($searchString,
                            $searchRange.Cells(1,1),
                            [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn]::xlValues,
                            [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt]::xlWhole
                        )

# NOT FOUND
if ($search -eq $null) {
        

    Write-Host "Not found"

}

else { # FOUND

    Write-Host "Found at row #" -NoNewline
    Write-Host $search.Row

}

# Close Objects
if ($xlBook) { $xlBook.close() }
if ($Excel) { $Excel.quit() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `LookAt:=xlWhole` option to specify cells containing only "TTF":

```
$condition1 = "TTF"    
$fs1 = $ws.cells.find($condition1, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
$condition1 = "TTF"    
$fs1 = [void]$ws.cells.find($condition1, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt]::xlWhole)
```